# Laravel scope on collection

Tags: php, laravel

**I'm in Pain because of this problem.**

### Problem

I have `categories` table which contains `id`, `slug` and `parent_id`.

`lessons` table which contains `category_id` (the child of a `Category`)

I want by Eloquent scope get all lessons posted by `Category` parent `id`

example:

> parent category of `id=1` have children categories of ids `3`, `4` and `5`.
>
> Then retrieve `Lesson`s under the parent category of `id=1`, **so this must return the lessons of all of the childrens**.

**Categories table**

[image]

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}


public function lessons()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        \App\Lesson::class, \App\Category::class,
        'parent_id', 'category_id', 'id'
    );
}

//Pointless try
// public function scopeGetParent($query, $slug)
// {
//  $query->where('slug', $slug)->first()->lessons;
// }

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

**Lessons.php**

```
                    return Lesson::recentLessons()
                    ->byParentCategory($args['category'])
                    ->simplePaginate($page)
                    ->shuffle();
```

how can I construct scopeByParentCategory() function??

**sorry for the fuzzy question! Spent 3 hours trying :(**

**update**: I got this idea right after posting the question but still wanna know what do you think about it and if this the best way to handle it.

```
    public function scopeByParentCategory($query, $slug)
{
    $ids = [];
    foreach (Category::where('slug', $slug)->first()->children as $value)
    {
        $ids[] = $value->id;    
    }

    return $query->whereIn('category_id', $ids);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First put this code inside of your `Category` model:

```
public function scopeOfSlug($query, $slug)
{
   $query->where('slug', $slug);
}
```

Then in your controller

```
return Category::ofSlug($args['category'])
                ->lessons
                ->simplePaginate($page)
                ->shuffle();
```

Comment: thank you for answering in short notice,  but I want to apply other scopes on lessons.

Comment: Can you update your question with all the `check` you want to do with some code you already wrote?